# Empty div height issues under IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, height

I want to implement a empty div with background color in it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .dark_green {
            background-color: #00D100;
            width: 20px;
            height: 4px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dark_green"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Under IE7/8/9 the height of this div is not 4px, it automatically change to 19px; Under FF and other chrome it is right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
font-size: 4px;
```

Answer (score 3):

It kind of depends on what you are trying to do. There are a few things that would work:

```
    .dark_green {
        [...]
        line-height:4px;
    }
```

or

```
    .dark_green {
        [...]
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Would both work.

The reason this is happening is because the text in your DIV (even if it's just whitespace) has a rendered line-height of 19px. The problem browsers are using that value instead of what you are setting as a fallback to not cut off text. Telling the browser that you want the text smaller (`font-size:4px;`), the line height smaller (`line-height:4px;`), or the text to get cut off (`overflow:hidden;`) should correct the issue.

The reasons I wouldn't use font-size in this context are:

1. It only works because the the line-height that is inherited when you
   apply the new font size, so you might as well just set the correct
   property.
2. Certain browsers have a minimum font size which is larger than 4px
   (11px on FF, not sure if you can set this in IE), meaning that if
   the user had a larger minimum set, your fix wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Add a doctype as the very first line such as `<!DOCTYPE html>`, to escape [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). This is an important thing to do, or you'll have endless problems with IE.

Once you've done this, your original code will work in IE7 and greater just like it does in Firefox/Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

add any item to the div you want to collapse, and set the display on that element to none.

if your problem div is

```
<div class="collapseToZero"></div>
```

Add something like this:

```
<span class="nothing"></span>
```

and add this style for the class

```
.nothing{display:none;}
```

and your resulting HTML will look like this

```
<div class="collapseToZero">
   <span class="nothing"></span>
</div>
```

Now ie 7 will render your problem div with a height of zero instead of font size.

Answer (score 0):

Another way - just to throw this into the mix: add an empty comment as the divs content. Yes its adding extra markup but it does work:

```
<div><!-- --></div>
```